# Form1 GridView is not accessible by Form 2 Button

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I am trying to interact the DataGridView, located in Form1 (frPlanDeLucru), by a button in Form2. The reason for this is to create a separate search window. I keep getting Error CS0122, frPlanDeLucru.dataGridView1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Please help.

The Code in Form 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Plan_de_lucru
{
    [Serializable()]
    public partial class frPlanDeLucru : Form
    {
        public frPlanDeLucru()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void ctrlLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + TextBox1.Text + "; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            new Form2().Show();
            this.Show();
        }



            }
        }
```

The code in Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String str = "select * from searchBox where ( Name like '%' + @search + '%')";
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = frPlanDeLucru.dataGridView1.DataSource; //<- Here is the problem, do not know the fix



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Form2:**

```
public DataGridView Dgv { get; set; }
```

**In Form1:**

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Dgv = dt; //Add this to the ctrlLoad_Click
```

In Form2 access its own Dgv propety.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a reference to form a when creating form b and expose a public method / property in that "formA" that returns the datasource you wish. An example in which this is used:

```
public class FormA
{
   public FormA()
   {
   }

   public object GetDataSource()
   {
      return datagrid1.DataSource.ToObject();
   }
}

public class B
{
    private A _formA;

    public B(A formA)
    {
       _formA = formA;
    }

    private void GetDataSourceFromA()
    {
        object dataSource = _formA.GetDataSource();
    }
}
```

This might lead to another problem though; the second form being on a different thread. Calling objects on the first form from a different thread is not possible, [more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx), though I think out of scope for your question.

Comment: This might need delegates and an Invoke call for thread safety, too.

Comment: btw, shouldn't that `GetDataSourceFromA` be a `private Object` instead of a `public void`? Unless that's just your example of using the `FormA.GetDataSource()`...

Comment: Private is arguably better. The return type however, depends on your needs. This is just an example.

Comment: Right. It's just a usage example. The way you wrote it made it look like a part of the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I found that Form1 GridView was set to private... i entered in the code behind Form1 and modified it to private.
Cheers.

Comment: Don't change the code in `Form1.Designer.cs`, instead open `Form1` in design mode, then select your gridview and in properties window, change the `Modifiers` property to `Public`.